# Charts.js - How to create a custom X axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to create a mix chart, a bar chart with a line chart. Below is a picture of a standard example.

[image]

I need to change the x-axis as shown in the picture below, how can I do that?

[image]

In other words, I want to remove the dependence of x-axis labels on the number of bars and their points and make the x-axis arbitrary, which sets the maximum and minimum values and its step

Answer (score 0):

Change the labels as shown in this example:

```
const data = {
  // Put whatever you want
  labels: [0, 5, 10, 15, 20],
  datasets: [
    {
     /* ........ */
    },
  ]
};
```

Comment: the problem is that if, for example, we have 10 bars, and I want to draw only 5 values ​​on the x-axis, then if I set 5 values ​​in the labels array, then on the chart I will see only 5 bars, and not all 10

Comment: you can set labels array dynamically depending on your situation, sorry i cant debug only photos, provide some code to make it easier to help

Comment: I thinks I found a solution, I need to set a new x-axis of type 'linear', in which I simply set the maximum and minimum values

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, we need to add a new dataset and bind it to a custom X axis.

```
datasets: [{
            type: chartTypes.Line,
            xAxisID: 'custom-X-axis',
        },
/*...*/]
```

Then we need to add this custom axis and hide the default one

```
scales: {
            xAxes: [
                {
                    display: false,
                }, {
                    id: 'custom-X-axis',
                    type: 'linear',
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 20,
                    }
                }
            ],
}
```